# Flutter commands not working in the Terminal

Tags: flutter, terminal, path

I have downloaded flutter and completed my setup am sure its good as I have checked it 5 times and put the correct file path export PATH="$PATH:/Users/KingKimani/Developer/flutter/bin". but I can't run flutter doctor or any flutter command why?
I am currently using the MAC M1 chip.

Comment: how is this related to Java?

Comment: restart/reload your terminal configurations example - source ~/.zshrc

Comment: I just removed the java flag

Answer (score 0):

If you are using zsh do the following.

1. Open .zshrc file nano $HOME/.zshrc
2. You will see the commented $PATH variable here

```
# If you come from bash you might have to change your $PATH.
# export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/...
```

3. Remove the comment symbol(#) and append your new path using a separator(:) like this.

export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/KingKimani/Developer/flutter/bin:$PATH

Activate the change

```
source $HOME/.zshrc
```

You're done !!!

Comment: am using bash, and do u want me to delete the path and rewrite it as  "export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/KingKimani/Developer/flutter/bin:$PATH" ?

Answer (score 0):

After setting the correct path on the system.

System terminal needs to have latest environment configurations.

Restart/Reload terminal required.

If you are using zsh shell & have save path on .zshrc file.
below command will reload configurations

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

[Reference](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#update-your-path)